# Find the solution of the differential equation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+5\frac{dy}{dx}-14y=18e^{2x}$ given that y=2 and $\frac{dy}{dx}=-21$ when x =0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know that this is a second order differential equation, but its the last question in my homework set and I dont know where to even start.

How would I go about solving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Using characteristic equation to solve the homogeneous equation first, where the characteristic equation is $r^2 +5r-14=0$. Then use undetermined coefficients to find the particular solution.

Notice that the general solution will have a $e^{2x}$ term. So when you try the particular solution, you should try $xe^{2x}$ first.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions to the homogenious equation 
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+5\frac{dy}{dx}-14y=0
$$
are $$
y = Ae^{2x}+Be^{-7x}
$$

To this we must add a specific solution to the full equation.  To get that, let $y = ue^{2x}$. Then
$$
\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}+9\frac{du}{dx}=18
$$
This is easy to solve by letting $v = \frac{du}{dx}$.  You end up with 4 free parameters, but two of then collapse into the two others, giving you two degrees of freedom to impose the initial conditions.